# Что указать в качестве значения по умолчанию в заголовке пользовательской функции для корректной работы стандартных функций Python?

Tags: python, функции, аргументы, default

Целиком мой вопрос звучит так:

Что указать в качестве значения по умолчанию в заголовке пользовательской функции, чтобы стандартные функции Python воспринимали это значение как отсутствие аргумента или как своё значение по умолчанию?

Поясню.

У меня есть собственная простенькая функция. Некоторые аргументы хочу сделать необязательными. Эти аргументы в теле моей функции передаются стандартным функциям Python. Какое значение по умолчанию у этих аргументов мне указать в заголовке моей функции, чтобы стандартные функции Python'а вели себя так, как если бы им **не передавали** эти аргументы?

Вот мой код, упрощённо:

```
def my_plots(column, max_x=None):
    df.plot(kind='hist', y=column, range=(0, max_x))
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в случаях, когда я указываю значение аргумента `max_x` при вызове моей функции, график рисовался бы до этого значения по оси `X`, а если не указываю, чтобы происходило автомасштабирование, как если бы стандартной функции plot не передавалось нкакого значения.

`None` для этих целей не годится - код падает с ошибкой. Пробовал также `[]`, `()` и `_` - тоже ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_plots(column, max_x==None):
    if max_x==None:
       df.plot(kind='hist', y=column)
    else:
       df.plot(kind='hist', y=column, range=(0, max_x))

my_plots(10)
my_plots(10, max_x=10)
```

Comment: Сергей, такой код строит мне гистограмму в неправильном масштабе. В случае вызова функции в 4-й строке (без указания max_x), он отбрасывает все значения по оси X больше единицы, указанной в первой строке Вашего кода. А мне нужно вместо единицы какое-то значение или что-то, что воспринимается функцией plot как отсутствие аргумента.

Comment: поправил  код тока так

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Да, спасибо, такой вариант - рабочий (только один знак равенства в 1-й строке лишний).
А как быть, если у меня таких необязательных аргументов несколько? - Перебирать все возможные сочетания?
Это вопрос со звёздочкой))

Comment: А если range=(0, 0)) то какой будет результат?

Comment: Рисует от -0,4 до 0,4...

Comment: "Перебирать все возможные сочетания?" Даже не знаю как на этот вопрос правельно ответить. Вкратце, не вдаваясь в подробности по обстоятельтвам